# SVM Scikit-Learn : Why prediction time decrease with SVC when increasing parameter C?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, latency

I’m trying to evaluate the influence of the # of features & parameter C (SVM regularization) on the prediction time. I am using a modified version of [code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_prediction_latency.html#example-applications-plot-prediction-latency-py) proposed by scikit-learn website.

Here are some key lines of code :
input

```
'n_train': int(2000),
'n_test':  int( 500),
'n_features': np.arange(10,100,10)
```

Functions

```
SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.001)
SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.01)
SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
SVC(kernel='linear', C=100)
```

predictions

```
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
....
start = time.time()
estimator.predict(X_test)
runtimes[i] = time.time() - start
```

Output : [Evolution of Prediction Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3nea.png)
[image]
I don’t understand why the prediction time is reversed. According to many resources ([3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel) and others), the latency should increase with C parameter of SVM function.

Comment: This question really belongs in [Cross Validated.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a bit odd indeed...

Answer (score 0):

Having a larger C will lead to smaller values for the slack variables. This means that the number of support vectors will decrease. When you run the prediction, it will need to calculate the indicator function for each support vector.

Thus; smaller C -> more support vectors -> more calculations -> slower predictions.

Comment: Not necessary. It's the contrary that is said in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-rbf-parameters-py. I think the number of support vectors does not really depends on C but rather on the dataset